# how can I download application to add to several desktops so I woundn't download the apps on each computer from the internet?

Tags: installation, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I am helping a non-profit put ubuntu on donated computers to give to children. We Install ubuntu on a dozen computers a time. I was wondering if there is a method of choosing and downloading educational applications for ubuntu to put on a cd and use that or flash drive to install these applications on several computers simultaneously without using the internet.